# Adding filename to eachrecord of a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project where I download files from different businesses.  These files all contain the same relevant type of information.  I use a macro that merges all these files into a single workbook, but prior to using the macro I open each file, add a column name labeled "Business Name" and write the name of the business and carry it across each record.  That way when the files merge I know where the records came from.  I know the name of the business because each filename share the same pattern, which is the business name and then a metric (Ex: PapaJohn QualityScore).

I was wondering if there could be a macro that would do this, where it would take the first string of the file name and add it to each record of the table? 
The macro I'm using to merge all the files goes as follows:

---

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

    If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
        countFiles = 0
        countSheets = 0

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

        For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
            countFiles = countFiles + 1

            Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

            For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                countSheets = countSheets + 1
                wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
            Next

            wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Maybe This can Help:**

Change your Loop with this Loop, Also Declare the Variables at the Top `Dim c as Long, r As Long`

```
    For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
        countSheets = countSheets + 1
        c = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        wksCurSheet.Range(Cells(1, c + 1), Cells(r, c + 1)).Value = Split(wbkSrcBook.Name, " ")(0)
        wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)

    Next
```

This will add the workbook name as an Identifier in the Last column.

---

**Updated:**

```
    For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
        countSheets = countSheets + 1
        c = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        R = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        wksCurSheet.Range(Cells(2, c + 1), Cells(R, c + 1)).Value = Split(wbkSrcBook.Name, " ")(0)
        wksCurSheet.Cells(1, c + 1).Value = "Business Name"
        wksCurSheet.Range(Cells(2, c + 2), Cells(R, c + 2)).Value = Split(wbkSrcBook.Name, " ")(1)
        wksCurSheet.Cells(1, c + 2).Value = "Metric Name"
        wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!! This definitely is a step in the right direction.  I was wondering if you could help me out a bit more.  I only need the first string of the file name and not the second! Would there be a way to pull just the first string?  Thanks again!!

Comment: @Ronnie.j ... Use the Code now. It will Print the 1st String.

Comment: You're a wizard.  If I can bother you one more time, would there be any way to make the first row of the added column "Business Name"?

Comment: I tried to do it on my own by adding this modification but I get an error when I do this.  Would you be able to give me some insight? 
wksCurSheet.Range(Cells(1, c + 1)).Value="Business Name"
wksCurSheet.Range(Cells(2, c + 1), Cells(r, c + 1)).Value = Split(wbkSrcBook.Name, " ")(0)

Comment: @Ronnie.j , I Have added the updated answer. Hope I am not late :)

Comment: I appreciate all the help you've given me! This definitely has made the process much more smoother!! I was hoping you could help me one more time.  How could I get the second string in the file name to be a second column that gets added to every record?  If I could get the Business name and the metric name in each row then I can just select every file and run the macro.  I appreciate all that you've done!!

Comment: @Ronnie.j .. Use the Updated Answer. Also, I will appreciate a Upvote :)